# How to get the value from input and split them based on chars and numbers Js

Tags: javascript

I'm working on some exercise and I need help.
I have an input field where user can enter name and Id, with or without delimiters:
[image]

what I'm achieving is when I type "Jack123", it should identify the chars and numeric and separate it out and display in the following format:

```
Name: Jack
Id: 123
```

there could be a scenario where the user typed string will be "Jack 123" or "Jack-123" in all cases it should display the above o/p.

html:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" >
  <div class="name">
  Name:
  </div>
  <div class="id">
  Id:
  </div>
  <button onclick="changeText()">Submit
  </button>
</div>
```

css:

```
.name, .id {
  display:none; // will be displayed only when users inputs some text
}
```

js:

```
function: input (value) {
   value.split() // I'm not sure on what bases to split as this could have spaces,"-","." or even nothing
}
```

any idea on this approach.
thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To isolate only letters or numbers from a string I would use a regular expression.

```
var input = 'abc123';

// replace anything that isn't a-z or A-Z with ""
var letters = input.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '');

// replace anything that isn't 0-9 with ""
var numbers = input.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

console.log('letters', letters);
console.log('numbers', numbers)
```

This will result in

> letters abc
>
> numbers 123